# Do I use the inclusion-exclusion principle for this?

Tags: combinatorics, inclusion-exclusion

Consider $3$ digit integers from $000$ to $999$ (i.e., including leading zeroes).  Let $n_1$, $n_2$ and $n_3$ refer to the $1$st, $2$nd and $3$rd digit of each of these integers.  There are $1000$ such integers.  Using the inclusion-exclusion principle, it's simple to determine how many digits have, say, a $1$ in the first position or a $4$ in the second position or a $7$ in the 3rd position - i.e. [$1nn$ OR $n4n$ OR $nn7$].  (There are $271$ such integers.)

However, is there a technique for finding the number of integers that satisfy conditions such as:
[$1nn$ OR $n4n$ OR $nn7$] AND
[$2nn$ OR $n3n$ OR $nn7$] AND
[$1nn$ OR $n7n$ OR $nn9$]

EDIT: sorry, misstated the question originally.  By my reckoning, 29 integers meet these conditions.  For example, $977$ would meet the conditions despite not having a 1 or 2 in the first position.  $977$ meets each of the conditions separately.

This is a trivial example, I'm looking for a pointer to a general technique.

Thanks
CL

Comment: Use mathjax. [Click on this tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Your second statement is not equivalent to your first statement. The number 130 satisfies [$1nn$ OR $n4n$ OR $nn7$] AND
[$2nn$ OR $n3n$ OR $nn7$] AND
[$1nn$ OR $n7n$ OR $nn9$] but not ($n_1 = 1$ OR $2$) AND ($n_2 = 4$ OR $3$ OR $7$) AND ($n_3 = 7$ OR $9$).

Comment: Sorry, misstated the question - I hope it's clearer now.

Comment: $271 = 100 + 100 + 100 - 10 -10-10 + 1$ I agree. You can maybe apply some Booelan algebra to change your condition to an "or" of combined conditions again, or an "and" of negative conditions, to both of which we can apply inclusion-exclusion.

Comment: Thanks, I see what you mean - the problem is not as simple as I thought.